# problem to return an ee.image in api python EE

Tags: javascript, python, flask, google-app-engine

Tengo una web donde quiero mostrar indices de [NDVI](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%8Dndice_de_vegetaci%C3%B3n_de_diferencia_normalizada) del [Earth Engine](https://earthengine.google.com/) en ella para fin agropecuario.

Dispongo de un servidor PHP donde uso [Leaflet javascript](https://leafletjs.com/) para mostrar algunos poligonos, y otro servidor linux con la API de `Earth Engine` en Python y [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) para recibir las consultas.

Lo que he probado de hacer es que el cliente FrontEnd envie una consulta Ajax al servidor `Earth Engine` recibido por `Flask` y ejecute una tarea de obtener una [ee.Image](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_overview) (para que leaflet la agregue como capa) pero `Flask` no me deja devolverla al cliente

> ee.Image is not callable

Claramente no es un tipo de variable que se pueda devolver.

Entonces he pensado que tal vez deba hacer que la api EE genere una imagen `.tiff` (pero no se si la puedo devolver por `Flask`). O que guarde la imagen `.tiff` en un repositorio (En lo posible no quiero usar `GoogleDrive`) e inmediatamente el FrontEnd la cargue.

Sino, tambien he pensado que la api EE genere una `.png` de la capa coloreada y un [geojson](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON) con los datos para tratarlos aparte.

Estoy abierto a cualquier sugerencia.

Tal vez podria ser [algo como](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52974964/google-earth-engine-rgb-image-export-from-imagecollection-python-api) hizo Kel Markert, pero no sé como logró tomar de python `prettyImg` y pegarla en el map `leaflet`.

Muchas gracias equipo,
un saludo!

Aqui muestro código:
Javascript frontEnd, solicita la imagen de índice de producción:

```js
function mapp (){

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://nombredelservidor:5000/map2/',
                data: {valor : "GeojsonGeometry"}, //el contorno del lote
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function (data) {    
                  grupoCapas.addLayer(data); //AQUI LO AGREGARIA AL LEAFLET
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
                }
            });
            return false;
}
```

Del lado servidor python con gee:

ARCHIVO PRINCIPAL REQUEST:

```
@app.route('/map/')
def hacer2():
    return mapp.pr1(geometriaTraidoDelGet)
```

Llama al **siguiente archivo** `mapp.py` **que genera la imagen**, no es un algoritmo de índice de producción porque hice algo mucho mas simple solo para lograr devolver alguna imagen, una vez que tenga resuelto eso, continúo con el proyecto:

```
def pr1(geometry):

    collection = (ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1')
            .filterDate(datetime.datetime(2000, 4, 1),
                        datetime.datetime(2000, 7, 1)))
    image1 = collection.median()
    image = image1.select('B3')
    img = ee.Image(image.get(0))

    return img //aqui es donde sale el error al retornar
```

Por un lado es muy probable que `Flask` no pueda devolver ese tipo de objeto. Por lo que necesito encontrar la forma que `Python` en este último archivo tome la imagen (img) y la convierta/dibuje a `.tiff` o `.png`, ahí sí podría almacenarla y enviarsela al Javascript frontend `leaflet` que solicitó, e incorporarla como `overlays`.

Gracias!

Comment: Creo que para una mejor compresión de lo que sucede sería mejor que compartiera parte del código, algo así como lo hizo quien hizo la pregunta en el post de referencia

Comment: Podrías poner en la pregunta el código que utilizas? Cómo intentas devolver la `ee.Image` con Flask?

Comment: Acabo de agregar codigo, espero que se entienda, ya que está a medio construir (porque todo depende de cómo lo resuelva o si es posible o no). Gracias!